# How to find a line starting with 'a' and ending with 'c' using grep?

Tags: grep, regex

I have a file named `newfile`. The contents of this file are:

```
abc
xyz
abc
```

Now I want to find lines which start with `a` and end with `c`. I enter the following command but the results are not the same as expected by me:

```
grep -E   '^ac$' newfile
```

The problem with this command is that when I use `^ac$` the command interprets it as starting with `ac` instead of starting with `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem with this command is that when I use ^ac$ the command interprets it as starting with 'ac' instead of starting with 'a'.

Not really. Since you used the [`$` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), you are searching for the lines which end right after the `ac` string, so only lines containing exactly single `ac` and no more characters are matched.

To allow any characters between those letters, use the regex for any count of any characters: `.*`
(Or if you want to allow just one character like in `abc` in the example, use `.` without [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) like `*`.)

By the way, you can simply leave out the option `-E` for this regex, since it does not involve any syntax that would differ in these two variants.

So the result is:

```
grep '^a.*c$' newfile
```